# SignalR and Web Api - How to modify the Hub class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am looking to notify clients of my Web Api that other clients have authenticated using SignalR. I understand the basics of SignalR but I am confused as to how to modify the Hub such that it can work with an API request.

The client is a Single Page Application which makes use of jQuery to call the Web Api. The client first authenticates with the API before it can use any of the API endpoints.

Also should add that I am authenticating with OAuth in the same project as the Web Api.

Comment: Well, client could notify the server after the authentication. The server could then broadcast the message to all the other clients (as in the signalr chat for example)

Comment: @alessalessio - That sounds just what I am looking for. How do I go about adding the SignalR call into the authentication of the Web Api? Does the HTML page that makes the jQuery call to authenticate have to contains the SignalR scripts like the SignalR chat example? Might you have any example code?

Comment: It's not clear how your clients are authenticated, do they authenticate using OAuth in the same project as Web API? Are you using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - Sorry I didn't mention that. Yes, I am using OAuth in the same project as the Web Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way here is to get a reference to the signalR hub inside the oauth authentication flux, and then launch a global signaling after the successfull completion of this method: `Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)`.

For example:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        // auth and other stuffs removed for brevity
        // ...
        // ...
        context.Validated(ticket);

        // then here
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<IMessageHub>("MessageHub");
        hub.Clients.All.ServerMessage(new {message = $"{context.UserName} is here!"});

    }
```

with a message hub like this:

```
public interface IMessageHub
{
    void ServerMessage(object eventObject);
}

[HubName("MessageHub"), Authorize]
public class MessageHub : Hub<IMessageHub>
{
    public MessageHub()
    {

    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)